# Where am I going wrong with write to file in Python 3x?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a text file and write to it, I am very new to programming all together and I would like some advice.

```
#part1
def writetofile():
myFile = open("C:\Andrew\myText.txt", "a")
myFile.write(a)
myFile.close()

#part2
def textfileopen():
  bottle = ['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten' ]
  text_one = 'green bottles hanging on the wall'
  text_two = 'And if one green bottle should accidentally fall\nThere\'ll be'




for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    print(bottle[i], text_one)
    print(bottle[i], text_one)
    print(text_two, bottle[i-1])

textfileopen()
#part3
```

I was given an example:

```
def kevin():
File = open('abc.txt','a')
File.write(a)
File.close()



def skinner ():
kevin('rabbits')

skinner()
```

My program is suppose to execute from the "skinner" or "textfileopen" (Am i missing a python main block?) Part 3 is suppose to execute the program and call part 2 and then part 2 calls part 1 to create the text file. I know you cannot start a program with a def, I am making mistakes with my defs I think but I can't work out what exactly i am stuffing up. I could use some advice or help thanks.

Comment: My advice? Read the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the solid advice, i've read through tutorials for hours and I can't get my head around it.

Comment: Your indentation is wonky. Fix that.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that you define the filename as `"C:\Andrew\myText.txt"`. The problem with this is that python reads `"\A"` as one character because of the `\` (which is actually called the escape character).
You want an actual `\` in your string, which you can do in one of the following two ways:

```
open(r"C:\Andrew\myText.txt", "a")  # notice the use of `r`, for "raw string"
```

OR

```
open("C:\\Andrew\\myText.txt", "a")  # the first \ escapes the second, to give you a \
```

Comment: While it's good to point out using raw strings when using backslashes... `\A` is not an escape char... (nor is `\m`) - there's more deep seated issues such as the function never being called and not accepting arguments for instance...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am not sure if this is one of the issues as I had to set a specific path to create the file because it was trying to write to the root directory

Comment: @JonClements: I was trying to explain that `'\'` is the escape character. I would appreciate a clarifying edit to that end, if you see a better way to explain it. Also, OP's post is very underspecified. For one, it doesn't explain how the observed behavior diverges from the expected. So I went with what I thought was most likely to be the error

Comment: @inspectorG4dget At the moment, it's more of a problem that `writetofile` is never called and the whole `textfileopen` doesn't make sense (with or without the loop in it). So I believe an answer to this question requires a much more fundamental explanation of how to call functions and in what order they should be called, more than a specific issue regarding escape characters (which may happen in the future and so is worth pointing out) as the OP hasn't even reached that point :)

Comment: @JonClements: Good point. I'm just going to leave my answer here... just 'coz

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, try & use the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) for file handling.

Also, make function **return** things that are required. So that, we can use these things & the function does not have to itself manipulate stuff (which is most of the times dangerous for sensitive data)

Another python *hack* is the [`str.join()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). It is faster than all other methods & is more pythonic.

```
#part1
def writetofile(to_write):
    with open("C:\Andrew\myText.txt", "a") as myFile:
        myFile.write(to_write)

#part2
def textfileopen():
    bottle = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five',
              'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten' ]
    text_one = 'green bottles hanging on the wall'
    text_two = "And if one green bottle should accidentally fall\nThere'll be"

    all_lines = []
    for i in range(10, 0, -1):
        line1  = " ".join([bottle[i], text_one])
        line2  = " ".join([bottle[i], text_one])
        line34 = " ".join([text_two, bottle[i-1], text_one])
        all_lines.append("\n".join([line1, line2, line34]))
    return "".join(all_lines)

#print(textfileopen())
writetofile(textfileopen())
#part3
```